# How can I get my Droid prototype and iOS prototypes to not say "load failed" on Xamarin for Visual Studio?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I just updated my Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 and I've tried to google this but I can't really find a solution that works for me.

["Load failed" and it sometimes says my Droid prototype is incompatible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd4AV.png)

I've tried to make updates and everything. I know the issue probably stems from my computer dying near the end of the installation.

Comment: Have you tried a reinstall? Perhaps all the Xamarin bits weren't installed correctly.

Comment: @Dominic That's what I ended up having to do. Thank you for your help!